# Does Docker on Ubuntu require Hyper-V?

Tags: docker, hyper-v

I am planning to install Ubuntu as the main operating system. I am currently using Windows 10 with virtual machine. I need to use Docker to manipulate programming development environment. But I do not have and for now I can not have a processor with Hyper-V.

So I have this question: Does Docker on Ubuntu require Hyper-V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, a container is not a virtual machine. It is a regular OS process in an environment bubble, so no virtualization is implied.

Windows has to jump through hoops to run Docker containers (that are mostly Linux things) and one of the hoops is a small virtual machine.